# get the number of users in a voice channel with my discord bot in python

Tags: discord, bots, channel

I'm looking for a way to get the number of users in a voice channel and to get their username to use it in one of my discord bot command, I found that I can use ctx.guild.member to get the members of users in the server, but not in a specific channel, is there a method to do that ?

I tried this

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(),command_prefix = "/")

@bot.command()  
async def teamup(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.VoiceChannel
```

Or this

```py
bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(),command_prefix = "/")

@bot.command()  
async def teamup(ctx):  
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

None of them works, the first tells me that member objects has no attribute VoiceChannel
and the second one tells me that ctx.message.author.voice is a NoneType object and has no attribute channel

Comment: What is `ctx` in this example? Can you provide more code so we can understand the context for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: VoiceChannel's have a [`members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members) attribute which gets you all the members in that voice channel.

Comment: @ESloman ty for your help, but my problem is not yet about getting the members, it is about getting the channel object from the author of the message

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.

```py
@bot.command()  
async def teamup(ctx):  
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

[`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) has an [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) property; this returns the [user/member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.voice) object for the individual that invoked the command. The user/member has a `voice` property that returns the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState) object of the user. This has a [`channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel) property which will return the voice channel that the user is in. Importantly, this will be `None` if the user isn't in a voice channel. So, putting it together:

```py
@bot.command()
async def teamup(ctx):
    voice = ctx.author.voice
    if not voice.channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not currently in a voice channel")
        return
    channel = voice.channel
    # do what you want with the channel here
    await ctx.send(f"You're in {channel.name}!")
```